# Crear boton de like en React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

***Contexto de la app:***

Es una app muy basica, se conecta con la API de unsplash para obtener fotos de acuerdo a alguna palabra que busque el usuario y me trae 20 fotos sobre esa tematica.

Las fotos se presentan en cards donde tambien se imprime su titulo, la cantidad de likes que posee (info brindada en el obj que me trae la api), el nombre del usuario que la subio y los tags.

***Estructura de la app:***

**App.jsx -> Cards.jsx -> Info.jsx**

**En App** claramente estan los demas componentes como navbar, la llamada a la API, un **useState**([image, setImage]) donde se guarda en json del resultado de la API (todas las fotos de la busqueda actual se almacenan allí). **Usando un image.map llamo al componente de Cards**.

En Cards se renderiza cada card con las imagenes y la info (que por cierto Info es otro componente). A este componente le llega como prop todo el objeto de una foto. En este componente llamo al componente **Info** (hijo de Cards)

El componente **Info** es para renderizar con mas orden (se podria hacer en el mismo componente de cards) la cantidad de likes y el nombre del ususario (sumado a iconos de corazon y de user). Aqui es donde hago uso de image.likes donde esta almacenado la cantidad de likes de cada foto.

***Primera solución:***

Lo primero que intente fue crear una funcion llamada **handleLike** en **App** que es enviada como prop a sus hijos y **llamada desde el btn del corazon en Info** mandando como parametro el id de la foto. Luego en App utilizo handleLike para buscar el registro dentro del state image y **le sumo 1 a lo existente**. **El problema de esto es que en la pagina no se vuelve a renderizar el like pero si hago un console.log de ese reguistro, los likes van subiendo.**

```
 //declaracion del state
 const [image, setImage]= useState([])

 const handleLike = (id) =>{
    image.map(img =>{
      if(img.id == id){
        img.likes + 1
      }
    })
  }
```

[image: Res de API unsplash]

**SOLUCIÓN DE BOTON COMPLETA**:
Dentro del json (de la API de unslpash) de mas arriba se puede observar un campo llamado "liked_by_user" este campo es el que usaremos para saber si el usuario le dio like o no a la publicación.

El siguiente codigo es el boton de like donde en el codigo del SVG el atributo fill tiene una condicional para manejar el comportamiento del color. Si liked_by_user === false significa que el usuario no le dio like y por ende esta en color negro o el color por default.

```
<button className="like" onClick={() => handleLike(data.id)}>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill={data.liked_by_user? `red` : `currentColor`} className="bi bi-heart-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path fillrule="evenodd" d="M8 1.314C12.438-3.248 23.534 4.735 8 15-7.534 4.736 3.562-3.248 8 1.314z"/>
        </svg>
    </button>
    {data.likes}
```

Ahora viene lo interesante. En la funcion handleLike, llamada desde el btn de like, hacemos un find para obtener el registro al cual se le dio like y lo guardamos en una variable auxiliar. Lo mismo hacemos con la variable liked donde guardamos si true o false.

Luego, preguntamos si es true o false, en caso de false se le setea al estado de la imagen +1 like y en caso de que sea true, se le resta ya que significa que al usuario le gustaba pero decidio sacarle el like.

Y para finalizar, se setea el valor liked_by_user con su contrario ya que si hago click es para cambiar ese estado a su contraparte.

```
  const handleLike = (id) =>{
let img = image.find((image=> id == image.id))
let liked = img.liked_by_user
if(liked === false){
  setImage([...image],[img.likes += 1])
}else{
  setImage([...image],[img.likes -= 1])
}
setImage([...image], [img.liked_by_user = !liked])
```

}

No se si será la mejor solución, pero como dije en otro comentario, no encontre ejemplos ni post ni tutoriales para poder crear un boton de estas caracteristicas ni en español ni en ingles.

Comment: Por favor, evita subir imágenes cómo código. Revisa [ask]

Comment: Hola @JheymanMejia, no es codigo, es un json para entender el contexto. Entre al link del enlace y no dice nada de no publicar images ni de codigo ni en general. Gracias por la repuesta, evitare hacerlo en el futuro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los likes no se renderizan por que los estas sumando directo.
Tendrias que usar el set state

```
var nuevoLike= img.likes+1
this.setState({ img.likes: nuevoLike });
```

Comment: Hola @AgustinSilva, gracias por contestar, probe de varias forma poder utilizar tu repuesta pero no funciona, voy a dejar la estructura del image como actualizacion del post a ver si el fallo es por ahi

Answer (score 2):

logré encontrar **la solución para que incrementen los likes** y se mantengan el resto en orden. Creo que es interesante compartir esto porque hay muy pocos foros donde se habla de un boton de likes como tal en un contexto de una app similar a instagram o pinteres.

La explicación del codigo seria: Dentro de la funcion handleLike que se llama desde el evento onClick del boton del like, se hace un setState copiando el arreglo y con el find para encontrar el registro donde hay que aplicar el cambio.

Creo que para que esto en serio sea un boton de like donde se +1 y se -1 dependiendo de lo que el usuario toque. Se podria hacer con un context o redux con dispatch.

```
 const handleLike = (id) =>{
    setImage([...image],[image.find((image=> id == image.id)).likes += 1])
  }
```